# R - how to remove log(value) = 0 in ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

my code is:

```
ggplot(test.data,aes(x=log(out),y=log(n))) + geom_point(aes(colour="red"))
```

then I get:

[image]

But I don't want log(out) = 0 or log(n) = 0 to be plotted

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to first exclude (or replace them by `NA`) all such values (i.e. `n==1` & `out==1`) and then plot it. This is many time useful if one want to show zeros in the plot. For e.g.

> Something like your plot

```
test.data = data.frame ( sample (1:10,100,replace=TRUE), sample (1:10, 100, replace=TRUE) )
names (test.data) <- c("out","n")
ggplot(test.data,aes(log(out),log(n)))+geom_point(aes(color="red")) 
+ xlim (0, 2.5) + ylim (0, 2.5) # just to get same range
```

[image]

> (Probably) something you want

```
 dd = apply (test.data,1,function(row) all (row!=1)) # find when neither out nor n is 1
 df = test.data[dd,] # take only
 ggplot(df,aes(log(out),log(n)))+geom_point(aes(color="red"))
   + xlim (0, 2.5) + ylim (0, 2.5) # just to get same range
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to either filter out the data of `test.data` - which you can do by performing the log  function prior to plotting and filtering the data,  or....  you could try setting the x and y limits to something like

```
+ xlim(0.0001, 10) + ylim(0.0001,10)
```

You have to make the first value large enough that it's above 0 but doesn't include data you want to plot.

Answer (score 1):

You could just subset the data before plotting, as in:

```
ggplot(subset(test.data, out!=1 & n!=1), aes(x=log(out),y=log(n))) +
  geom_point(aes(colour="red"))
```